# Not able to authenticate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error in Laravel latest for authentication

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given,
>   called in
>   G:\xampp\htdocs\newrestaurantcrm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php

can anyone give me an idea about this error why this error is occurring?
I am using below code for authentication in my `Auth\AuthController.php` file

```
protected function login(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = bcrypt($request->password);
    if (Auth::login(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

I changed the `protected` to `public`, `Auth::login()` to `Auth::attempt()`. If you use `login`, you will actually have to pass the `User object` you like to login as. You do not need to encrypt the password to pass to attempt and. To make this simpler you can write

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that your form has correct name for fields, `email` and `password` and also has same field `email` and `password` in `users` table as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you are authenticate user against `email` and `password` then use `Auth::attempt` or `Auth::once` (*For single request*). When we have user instance and we want to login with that user instance then we use `Auth::login`. For your case use `Auth::attempt` like this

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = bcrypt($request->password);
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: the plain text password gets passed to `attempt`

Comment: @lagbox it is encrypted `$password = bcrypt($request->password);` please check it carefully

Comment: I have try both solution which provide by you both but still same problem

Comment: @AdarshBhatt can you try changing `protected` to `public` ? If that didn't work then please post your `User` model in question

Comment: Now i got this error "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array given,

Comment: Please add your User model in question. Your user model should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. But better you add your user model in your question

Comment: @AdarshBhatt add your admin model in question not in my answer. i got your problem, you are trying to authenticated against your admin model, do you have `User` model too ?

Comment: @AdarshBhatt If you have user model and admin model both then you need to add extra guard in `config/auth.php`. If Admin model only then need to change the existing guard in `config/auth.php`. Add your  `config/auth.php` code in question too